# React render not executing in order

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got two react classes which are supposed to build a table which calculates totals for various properties.

In my main class, I've got:

```
const TableComponent = React.createClass({

    resetRowTotals: function() {
        console.log("Resetting");
        this.total1 = 0;
        this.total2 = 0;
        this.total3 = 0;
        this.total4 = new Set();
    },

    addToRowTotals: function(total1, total2, total3, total4) {
        console.log("Updating");
        this.total1 += ...;
        this.total2 += ...;
        this.total3 += ...;
        this.total4.add(...);
    },

    render: function() {
        this.resetRowTotals();

        this.tableRows = this.props.items.map(item => React.createElement(TableRow, {..., addToRowTotals: this.addToRowTotals}));

        console.log(this.total1, this.total2, this.total3, this.total4);

        return React.createElement("table", {id: "..."},
            React.createElement("thead", {},
                React.createElement("tr", {},
                    React.createElement("th", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("th", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("th", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("th", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("th", {}, ...)
                )
            ),
            React.createElement("tbody", {},
                React.createElement("tr", {},
                    React.createElement("td", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("td", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("td", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("td", {}, ...),
                    React.createElement("td", {}, ...)
                ),
                this.tableRows
            )
        )
    }
});
```

And for my row component I've got:

```
const TableRow = React.createClass({

    getVal2: function() {...},

    getVal3: function() {...},

    getVal4: function() {...},

    render: function () {
        let val1 = this.props....;
        let val2 = this.getVal2();
        let val3 = this.getVal3();
        let val4 = this.getVal4();

        this.props.addToRowTotals(val1, val2, val3, val4);

        return React.createElement("tr", {},
            React.createElement("td", {}, this.props....),
            React.createElement("td", {}, val1),
            React.createElement("td", {}, val2),
            React.createElement("td", {}, val3),
            React.createElement("td", {}, val4)
        )
    }
});
```

However, when I take a look at the table that gets created, all of the table rows are fine, but the total row (at the top of the table) is displaying all 0s

When I look at the console to see the order of execution for my functions I see:

```
Resetting
0 0 0 Set(0) {}
Updating
```

What I expect:

```
Resetting
Updating
(total1's value) (total2's value) (total3's value) Set(x) {(total4 values)}
```

It doesn't appear that the code is getting executed in order.

The totals should get reset, then then the main rows get created which calls the addToRowTotals function, and then just to make sure the data is correct for the totals, I log all 4 total values.

Why is it that console is logging the total values before I'm creating my table rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is actually getting called in the order you specified. You're only invoking the `addToRowTotals` method in the render method of your `TableRow` component, which doesn't get called until the invocation of `this.tableRows` at the end of the main component's render method. In other words, calling mapping the `items` array of the main component's props won't actually invoke the `TableRows`'s render method; only an attempt to render the mapped components will.

Thus, the order of execution is correct. To get what you are trying to achieve, you may want to think about where the `val#` variables are being stored, and whether you can call the `addToRowTotals` method in the main component, or else figure out a way to re-render the main component after this method is invoked.

Comment: Wait actually this is starting to sound wrong to me - can you try first simply binding the `addToRowTotals` to the main element? Basically, the props you pass down to the `TableRow` components (in the map call) should look like this: `{..., addToRowTotals: this.addToRowTotals.bind(this) }`

Comment: Also, I think this is where using component state would make more sense

Comment: Binding addToRowTotals doesn't seem to effect the functionality in any perceivable way.


I think you're quite right about questioning where the val# variables are being stored. It's just a shame because I want the components to be independent from each other (but having children still able to call specific parent functions with new data).


Before I do that, I tried using componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) to calculate the values and pass them back to the parent before the render occurs, however this just makes the code even more unreliable and unusable.

Comment: Interesting; usually, we must keep track of the value of `this` when passing down methods to child components. I can totally relate to this; I recently built an app where I had to move the data storage out of the main view controllers. I've come to build my apps using a logic component with view components as children; this way, my components can be reused cross platform. Anyways, sorry for the ramble; I'm glad you got things working!